# Django REST Framework API to update database

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

My Django model is

```
class CricketTeam(models.Model):
    dateCreated = models.DateField()
    captain = models.ForeignKey(Players)     
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coaches)
    physician = models.ForeignKey(Physicians)
```

Players, Coaches and Physicians are models defined in other applications.

I am looking to use Django Rest Framework generic class based views to call an API from Android/iOS and update the database table.

What should be my approach? Similar code samples will help a great deal. Thans

Answer (score 1):

Considering you only need to perform `update` operation you can inherit your `views` from `UpdateAPIView`.

Here is your `views.py` file:

```
class CricketTeamView(UpdateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CricketTeam.objects.all()
```

Here is your `serializers.py` file:

```
class CricketTeamSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CricketTeam
        fields = ('dateCreated', 'captain', 'coach', 'physician')
```

For detailed help you can visit Django Rest Framework's [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Comment: we cant update like that, we need to specify serializers in views.